# grunt concat_css disable output

Tags: css, gruntjs, concatenation

Is there anybody who is able to tell me how to disable the concat css output?

```
 Running "concat_css:main" (concat_css) task
[ 'tmp/styles/custom/style.css',
  'tmp/styles/custom/style.pref.css' ] 'tmp/styles/custom.min.css'
{ path: 'tmp/styles/custom/style.css',
  css: '/ =================================\n    MIXINS\n==================================== /\n/ =================================\n    COMPONENTS / FRAMEWORKS\n==================================== /\nmeta.foundation-mq-small {\n  font-family: "only screen and (min-width: 768px)";\n  width: 768px;\n}\n\nmeta.foundation-mq-medium {\n  font-family: "only screen and (min-width:1280px)";\n  width: 1280px;\n}\n\nmeta.foundation-mq-large {\n  font-family: "only screen and (min-width:1440px)";\n  width: 1440px;\n}\n\n,\n*:before,\n*:after {\n  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;\n  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;\n  box-sizing: border-box;\n}\n\nhtml,\nbody {\n  font-size: 100%;\n}\n\nbody {\n  background: white;\n  color: #222222;\n  padding: 0;\n  margin: 0;\n  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica",
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you attached the grunt file

Comment: https://github.com/Acoustics/jbFE/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Comment: Are you trying to disable the task or just the output? Which of your grunt tasks are you running?

Comment: css_concat task, and I want to disable the output. when the task is running, it outputs the css, I want to disable that

Answer (score 0):

I checkout your project and executed the grunt targets In both cases `grunt` and `grunt concat_css`
 I donot get any detailed level output.

Below is the message I see in the console.

```
Running "concat_css:vendor" (concat_css) task
[] 'tmp/styles/vendor.min.css'
File "tmp/styles/vendor.min.css" created.

Running "concat_css:main" (concat_css) task
[] 'tmp/styles/custom.min.css'
File "tmp/styles/custom.min.css" created.

Done, without errors.

Elapsed time
loading tasks    2s
concat_css:main  15ms
Total            2s
```